# PowerShell script to change SharePoint Designer workflow status

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, powershell, powershell-script

I want to change the status of workflow using PowerShell script.

If you go into workflow settings in a library in SharePoint, and click on Remove a workflow, you see the 3 settings I'm referring to: "Allow", "No New Instances", and "Remove".

I'm thinking there must be a way to update these workflow settings from a PowerShell script.

based on four parameters:

Param 1 - Site URL

Param 2 - List/Library Name

Param 3 - Workflow Name

Param 4 - Status of WF ("Allow", "No New Instances", and "Remove")

Does anyone know how?

Comment: Whether you use SharePoint Online or SharePoint Server? Workflow 2010 or workflow 2013?

Comment: I am using SharePoint online and workflow is 2013